# border-image on top only, no slicing?

Tags: css

The CSS3 border-image seems to work by slicing and dividing an image.

Suppose I have a 20px square png of a star that I want to repeat along a top border only. How would I compose the CSS rule?

i.e. no slicing, no stretching, no round... just repeat a little square png along the top border only.

```
.div-with-top-border {
  border-image: url('/images/star.png') ? ? repeat?;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Repeat`: repeat, or tile, the image.

`Round`: tile the image but only so that a whole number of tiles fit.

Below code will create a top transparent border of `20px` and set the star.png image as background. The number in `border-image` much like the `border-width` property, and they are specified in the same order: top, right, bottom, left. You can use percentages or pixels. Strangely, the percentages require the "%", while pixels should be listed without the "px":

```
.div-with-top-border {
   border-top: 20px solid transparent;
   border-image: url('/images/star.png') 20 0 0 0 round;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer for more human readability.

Answer (score -2):

```
.div-with-top-border { 
   display: block; 
   border-top: 20px solid transparent; 
   background-repeat: repeat-y; 
   border-image: url('/images/star.png'); 
   border-bottom: 0; 
   border-left: 0; 
   border-right: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.[How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)